# Cisco VPN AnyConnect alternative for Android

Tags: android, open-source, vpn

Is there an maintained open source VPN client with which it is possible to connect via the Cisco encryption schema for Android?

Searching the F-Droid store only delivers OpenConnect, which seems discontinued and crashes on start.